# How to handle Molusce ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape?

Tags: qgis, change-detection, molusce

I have a problem in QGIS Molusce plugin. I opened two raster files represeting LULC of 2 years, and roads as a spatial variable. The result of geometry check was positive. On Area changes tab clicking Update tables results in a Python failure message: "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape". Does anyone have an idea what causes this failure message? (I tried this in different versions of QGIS - 1.8, 2.2, 2.6 resulting in the same message.)